# How do I create parameters in a Joomla module depending on another parameter / number?

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, xml, module-params

I'm trying to create a Joomla **module for typical CSS cards**, but I want to make the **number of cards dependent on a number input from the user**. For example the user wants 5 cards so in the parameter field "number of cards" he puts '5'.

Now he has to choose the text and logo for each card he wants, but how **can I 'spawn' parameter values during runtime?**

I could just put a set number of cards in and define the corresponding parameters in the modules XML, but is there a way to do it like I want to?

Comment: Please take our [tour] while you wait for feedback/support.

Comment: Have you looked at subforms? https://docs.joomla.org/Subform_form_field_type

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly how to make your question, but I used something similar to show a field conditioned to the value of another field in the 'showon' attribute with XML Path Language (XPath). I believe it is something similar. You can find out more at the link:

https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/

Comment: To be honest I have no idea how to achieve what I wanted with what you provided. Could you maybe explain or elaborate?